# How can I simulate emission of a standard key sequence?

Tags: qt, testing, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to test the "copy" functionality of my Qt widget by simulating emission of `QKeySequence::Copy`, but [`QTest::keyClick`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtest.html#keyClick) doesn't accept `QKeySequence` (or `QKeySequence::StandardKey`):

```
void QTest::keyClick ( QWidget * widget, Qt::Key key, Qt::KeyboardModifiers modifier = Qt::NoModifier, int delay = -1 ) [static]
void QTest::keyClick ( QWidget * widget, char key, Qt::KeyboardModifiers modifier = Qt::NoModifier, int delay = -1 ) [static]
```

I could just hardcode copy as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

```
QTest::keyClick(widget, Qt::Key_C, Qt::ControlModifier)
```

However that would be rather brittle and might fail when testing my widget in other environments, so I'd prefer to use `QKeySequence::Copy` if possible.

I know I can use [`QKeySequence::QKeySequence(StandardKey)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qkeysequence.html#QKeySequence-6) to find the primary binding, but I can't see how to extract the key and modifier(s).  Alternatively, is there some other way to get the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worked it out: the `operator[]` returns a bitwise combination of a `Qt::Key` and the `Qt::KeyboardModifiers` flags type (this doesn't seem to be documented anywhere).  So the way to extract the key and modifiers is to mask with `Qt::KeyboardModifierMask` (also completely undocumented):

```
QKeySequence binding(QKeySequence::Copy);
for (uint i = 0; i < binding.count(); ++i) {
    uint key = binding[i];
    QTest::keyClick(widget, Qt::Key(key & ~Qt::KeyboardModifierMask),
        Qt::KeyboardModifiers(key & Qt::KeyboardModifierMask));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`QKeySequence::keyBindings()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qkeysequence.html#keyBindings) method to get all available key sequences of the given `SequenceKey` and then extract the keys using the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034209/convert-string-representation-of-keycode-to-qtkey-or-any-int-and-back).

Alternatively you could convert every `QKeySequence` to string using the [`toString`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qkeysequence.html#toString) function, split the string to a `QStringList` using `+` as a separator and then convert every part of the list to the corresponding `Qt::Key` using a helper function.

```
QList<QKeySequence> bindings = QKeySequence::keyBindings(QKeySequence::Copy);
for (int i=0; i<bindings.count(); i++)
{
    QStringList keysList = bindings[i].toString().split("+");
    QVector<int> keys = getKeys(keysList);
}


QVector<int> getKeys(const QStringList& list)
{
    QVector<int> keys;
    for (int i=0; i<list.count(); i++)
    {
        if (list[i] == "Ctrl")
            keys << Qt::Key_Control;
        else if (list[i] == "F11")
            keys << Qt::Key_F11;
        else if (list[i] == "Ins")
            keys << Qt::Key_Insert;
        // add remaining modifiers
        // single letters
        else
            keys << list[i][0].toAscii();
    }
    return keys;
}
```

Comment: Converting via `toString` seems pretty inefficient.  It looks like `operator[]` is what I want, but how does the returned `uint` relate to `Qt::Key`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the accepted answer worked, however I discovered another simple way to do it (just want to add it here in case someone else is looking for a solution).

If using Qt 5.10 or later you can just call:

```
QTest::keySequence(widget, QKeySequence::Copy);
```

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest.html#keySequence-1