# How to cast a QChar to int

Tags: qt, casting, int, codepoint, qchar

In C++ there is a way to cast a char to int and get the ascii value in return. Is there such a way to do the same with a qchar? Since unicode supports so many characters and some of them are actually looking alike, it is sometimes hard to tell what one is dealing with. An explicit code point or a number that can be used to get such would be very helpful.

I searched a the web and this site for a solution but so far no luck, Qt documentation isn't much of help either, unless I'm overlooking something.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

Maybe I wasn't clear enough on the matter, sorry.

Here's some code:

```
char chChar = 'a';
cout << (int)chChar; // will output 97, not 'a'
```

Also, Qt allows this:

```
QChar ch = 'a';
if(ch == 0x61)
//...
```

As far as I can tell, there has to be some information relating to the unicode codepoint in the ch object. Any possibility to get it out of there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Took some time but I found the answer: `QChar` has a member named `QChar::unicode` which returns a `ushort` with its code point. Just for the record.

Comment: Yeah, but this does not yield the `int` required for `QKeyEvent` and `QApplication::sendEvent`. I think this may be what is needed: [Convert string representation of keycode to Qt::Key (or any int) and back](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034209/608639).